# How to remove underline when hovering over an image in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

[image]

I'm using data tables and each row in the table has a column for icons. I noticed that in Chrome and in Firefox when I hover over the icons, it changes colour (which is fine). However, in IE, when a user hovers over the icon, the icon is underlined  until the user moves the cursor. I have tried:

```
tr td a i:hover{

text-decoration: none !important;  
}
```

but that didn't work for me. I also wrapped the icons in a `display-inline` but it still doesn't work.
Please Help

Comment: I assume the image is wrapped in an anchor tag? Did you use "text-decoration: none !important;" on the anchor instead of the image? Can you show us your html/css?

Comment: you might also have a hover border on something ,remove that with border;0;

Comment: Could you help us by creating a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You have to show more code specific to you if a known documented solution for this problem is not working for you

Comment: hi, i have add my answer, you have to use border:none to img

Comment: Shouldn't the CSS be applied to the anchor and not the `i` element?

Comment: there already exists CSS that I have that changes the colour of the icon on hover, so why can't I apply the same logic and make this change in the same spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign the anchor tag a class:

```
<a class='NoUnderline'>blah blah</a>
```

Then take off the text decoration at the anchor tag level.  CSS:

```
a.NoUnderline
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give `border:none` to **image tag**

**CSS**

```
img{
 border:none;
}
tr td a:hover{

   text-decoration: none !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `:hover` selector to include `text-decoration: none;`

example:

```
yourelement:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow isaac. I'm reviewing your answer and would like to offer a few tips on how you can improve. First, when you write an answer make your you explain to the OP how it answers their question. Second, whenever possible try to link to official documentation to prove your concept. Lastly, please read the following article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

We really don't know what your environment is like with no code.

But you could try.

```
.element:hover {text-decoration: none; border: 0px}
```

or

```
img:hover {text-decoration: none; border: 0px}
```

If it doesn't work; try adding it with `!important` or within the `<head></head>` of your document. *(but if you coded this correctly you shouldn't have to do this kind of practice)*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the image itself doesn't have an underline but the anchor tag surrounding the image does.

To remove all underlines from the anchors you have to do this:

```
tr td a:hover{
   text-decoration: none !important;  
}
```

However, if you don't want to remove the underline from all anchors within a table cell, you would need to specifiy a class:

```
tr td a.nounderline:hover{
   text-decoration: none !important;  
}
```

And set the anchors class attribute to nounderline.